# populate DefaultTableModel after insert a row java

Tags: java

I am running a program with two frames. First one has a table, the second one has a form which allows adding a new user to the table. I think the problem is I didn't add a reference from the mainframe. I was trying different methods to refresh the mainframe programmatically, but it did not help so much. I read many articles on how to to it but I could find a solution. My table usually changes when I close my app and open it again. But I don't think is the right way to do it. I tried to delete elements from DefaultTableModel and populated jtable again, but did not get any results. Here is my code:

```
  public Vector vector_jtable = new Vector();  
    public MainApp() {
        initComponents();

        Database b =  new Database();

        b.getAmountOfRows(getCount);
 this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        printResultDB();
}
//add function that is responsible for addding data to the table
    public void postDataJtable() {
      System.out.println("The vector is: " + vector_jtable);
       Vector<String> header = new Vector<String>();

            header.add("Number"); 
            header.add("Name");
            header.add("First Payment");
            header.add("Next Payment");
            header.add("Picture");
            header.add("Phone");
            header.add("Amount");
            header.add("Age");
       model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable2.getModel();
            model.setDataVector(vector_jtable,header);


    }
```

I created a vector that allows putting data from the second frame.

```
   MainApp app;
    public AddStudents(MainApp a) {
        initComponents();

         app = a; 

        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jDateChooser1.setDateFormatString("yyyy-MM-dd");
         jDateChooser2.setDateFormatString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }
```

After that, I push the button to send it out and update the mainframe, but nothing happened:

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {


app.vector_jtable.add(name);
       app.vector_jtable.add(first_p);
       app.vector_jtable.add(next_p);
       app.vector_jtable.add(picture);
       app.vector_jtable.add(phone);
       app.vector_jtable.add(amount);
       app.vector_jtable.add(age);
        app.postDataJtable();
```

My question. How to add a row in jtable and refresh it. I really stuck in this topic. I need your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't update the Vector.

When you want to change the data in the table you need to change the data in the `TableModel`.

You can use the `addRow(...)` method of the `DefaultTableModel` to add a new row of data.

So the basic logic is:

```
Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();
row.add( someVariable1 );
row.add( someVariable2 );
...
modal.addRow( row ):
```

The model will then tell the table to repaint itself.

Edit:

There is no trick all you need is a reference to the model. Then you update the model.

Here is a simple example to prove the concept works:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class SSCCE extends JPanel
{
    private DefaultTableModel model;

    SSCCE()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        model = new DefaultTableModel(0, 2);
        JTable table = new JTable( model );
        add(new JScrollPane( table ));

        JButton button = new JButton( "Add Row" );
        add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        button.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();
                row.add( "" + model.getRowCount() );
                row.add( new Date().toString() );
                model.addRow( row );
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new SSCCE());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```

If it doesn't work for you then you need to debug your code. Maybe you have two "model" variables? Maybe you have to "table" variables. Maybe your code isn't even executed. Did you add any debug statements to the code to make sure it is executed.

We can't solve your problem only point you in the right direction.

Comment: I only can see changes when I restart my app.

Comment: Should I add this piece of code in function postDataJtable()? May you help me?

Comment: I don't know how you program works. You put the code in the method where you want to update the data in the table. The key point to my answer is that you need to update the "model" (and I showed you how to do this), not the original Vector.

Comment: Nothing happened, when I am trying to add vector with my elements into JTables: model =(DefaultTableModel) JTable.getModel(); model.addRow(row);

Comment: @Dennis, if you have a reference to the "model" of the JTable that is visible on the frame, then the code should work. See my edit. Don't forget to "accept" the answer because I proved the concept works. Now it is up to you to properly structure your code so that you have a reference to the "model" variable when you want to add a new row of data to the model.

Comment: Are there the same rules if I insert data from another frame?

Comment: Thanks, everything is working. How to add visibility for DefaultTableModel for the second frame, if I want to add a row in JTable from another frame?

Comment: @Dennis, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can try some aspects from this example below. The example has two `JFrame`'s - one with a `JTable` and the other the data entry fields. When the data is entered and the "UpdateTable" button is pressed (in the data entry class) the table is updated.

The example uses `java.util.Observer` and `Observable` to achieve this functionality.

The class with table:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.util.Observer;
import java.util.Observable;

public class TableUpdateTester implements Observer {

    private JTable table;
    private static final Object[] TABLE_COLUMNS = {"Book", "Author"};
    private static final Object [][] TABLE_DATA = {
        {"Book 1", "author 1"}, {"Book 2", "author 1"}
    };

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        TableUpdateTester tester = new TableUpdateTester();
        new DataEntryClass(tester);
    }

    public TableUpdateTester() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Update Tester");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(getTablePanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel getTablePanel() {
        table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(TABLE_DATA, TABLE_COLUMNS));
        JScrollPane scrollpane = new JScrollPane(table);
        scrollpane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 150));
        scrollpane.setViewportView(table);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(scrollpane);
        return panel;
    }

    // This is Observer's override method.
    @Override public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        String [] data = (String []) arg;
        System.out.println("Data recieving: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(data));
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
        model.addRow(data);
    }
}
```

The data entry class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Observable;

public class DataEntryClass {

    public DataEntryClass(TableUpdateTester observer) {

        final DataObservable observable = new DataObservable();
        observable.addObserver(observer);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Book: ");
        final JTextField text = new JTextField(15);
        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("Author: ");
        final JTextField text2 = new JTextField(15);
        JButton button = new JButton("Update Table");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String data1 = text.getText().isEmpty() ? "empty" : text.getText();
                String data2 = text2.getText().isEmpty() ? "empty" : text2.getText();
                String [] data = {data1, data2};
                System.out.println("Data sent: " + java.util.Arrays.toString(data));
                observable.changeData(data);
            }
        });

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(3, 2);
        panel.setLayout(grid);
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(text);
        panel.add(label2);
        panel.add(text2);
        panel.add(new JLabel(""));
        panel.add(button);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Data Entry");
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();
    }
}

class DataObservable extends Observable {
    DataObservable() {   
        super();
    }
    void changeData(Object data) {
        // the two methods of Observable class
        setChanged(); 
        notifyObservers(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution to my problem. I will post my code here.
The Mainframe. I know the app with two frames is not a good option, because it's hard to fix the problem and it usually takes a lot of time to debug it.

```
 /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public MainApp() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 689, 345);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        //add table in DefaultTableModel 
        model = new DefaultTableModel(0,2);
        table = new JTable(model);
        table.setBounds(58, 38, 524, 197);
        frame.getContentPane().add(table);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(0, 0, 4, 4);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Add");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //Call a second frame 
//add reference for DefaultTableModel and send it to another frame
                AddData frame = new AddData(model);
                frame.setVisible(true);


            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setBounds(239, 269, 117, 29);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
    }
```

The second frame, that is responsible for adding a new row in a table.

```
 /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public AddData(DefaultTableModel model) {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser();
        dateChooser.setBounds(115, 71, 188, 41);
        contentPane.add(dateChooser);

        JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Send");
        btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //MainApp app = new MainApp();
                Vector<Object> row = new Vector<Object>();
                row.add(""+model.getRowCount());
                row.add(dateChooser.getDate().toString());
                model.addRow(row);
            }
        });
        btnNewButton.setFont(new Font("Lucida Grande", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        btnNewButton.setBounds(165, 192, 117, 41);
        contentPane.add(btnNewButton);
    }
```

I found my mistake. I did not send a link of DefaultTableModel into the second frame. That's why it was null every time. It was a really painful experience, but I learned from my mistakes. Thanks, everyone for your help. I really appriciate.